# Html canvas scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page with a single element: a canvas of 3000x3000 and I'd like to center the browser scroll in a point (with variable coordinates) . I'm starter with html and javascript, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll a window: [window.scrollTo(x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollTo)